# Customize withStyles Material UI React styled components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I have a library of material-ui styled React components.

Styled components look like this:

```
import React from "react";
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";
import headerStyle from "material-kit-pro-react/assets/jss/material-kit-pro-react/components/headerStyle.jsx";

class Header extends React.Component {
    // ...
}
export default withStyles(headerStyle)(Header);
```

I want to customize the style of the component, but I want to keep the library untouched to avoid conflicts with future updates.

So I decided to create my own component:

```
import React from "react";
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";
import Header from "material-kit-pro-react/components/Header/Header.jsx";

export default withStyles(theme => ({
    primary: {
        color: "#000"
    }
}))(Header);
```

But with this approach the JSS engine creates two classes for the same component (Header-primary-25 WithStyles-Header--primary-12). That's not exactly a problem, but in my case there's a small conflict with a method in the component that expects only ONE class:

```
headerColorChange() {
    const { classes, color, changeColorOnScroll } = this.props;
    // ...
    document.body
        .getElementsByTagName("header")[0]
        .classList.add(classes[color]) // classes[color] is a string with spaces (two classes)
    ;
    // ...
}
```

Ok. It's not a big deal. I can modify that method and fix the problem.

But when I extend the class:

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "material-kit-pro-react/components/Header/Header.jsx";

export default class extends Header {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.headerColorChange = this.headerColorChange.bind(this);
    }
    headerColorChange() {
        const { classes, color, changeColorOnScroll } = this.props
        console.log(classes[color])
    }
}
```

I get this error related to withStyles:

```
withStyles.js:125 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '64a55d578f856d258dc345b094a2a2b3' of undefined
    at ProxyComponent.WithStyles (withStyles.js:125)
    at new _default (Header.jsx:11)
    at new WithStyles(Header) (eval at ./node_modules/react-hot-loader/dist/react-hot-loader.development.js (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:137520:54), <anonymous>:5:7)
```

And now I'm lost.

What's the best way to customize an already styled component?

How can I extend and override the constructor of a HoC (withStyles)?

**Edit to provide a better and minimal example:**

I have a component I can't modifiy because it's provided by a library:

`./Component.jsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";

class Component extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.headerColorChange = this.headerColorChange.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", this.headerColorChange);
    }

    headerColorChange() {
        const { classes } = this.props;

        // THIS FAILS IF classes.primary IS NOT A VALID CLASS NAME
        document.body.classList.add(classes.primary);
    }

    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return <div className={classes.primary}>Component</div>
    }
}

export default withStyles(theme => ({
    primary: {
        color: "#000"
    }
}))(Component);
```

I want to customize the primary color of the component. The straight way:

`./CustomizedComponent.jsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";

import Component from "./Component";

export default withStyles({
    primary: {
        color: "#00f"
    }
})(Component)
```

Ok. The color of the  has changed to #0ff. But then the component fails in `document.body.classList.add(classes.primary)` because classes.primary contains two class names concatenated (Component-primary-13 WithStyles-Component--primary-12). If I were allowed to modify the original component there would be no problem. But I can't, so I decided extend it and override the headerColorChange:

`./CustomizedComponent.jsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";

import Component from "./Component";

class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.headerColorChange = this.headerColorChange.bind(this);
    }

    headerColorChange() {
    }
}

export default withStyles({
    primary: {
        color: "#00f"
    }
})(MyComponent)
```

But then I get the error:

```
withStyles.js:125 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '64a55d578f856d258dc345b094a2a2b3' of undefined
    at ProxyComponent.WithStyles (withStyles.js:125)
    at new MyComponent (Header.jsx:7)
    at new WithStyles(Component) (eval at ./node_modules/react-hot-loader/dist/react-hot-loader.development.js (http://0.0.0.0:8080/bundle.js:133579:54), <anonymous>:5:7)
    at constructClassInstance (react-dom.development.js:12484)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:14255)
```

Questions are:

Is it possible to fully override the styles of the component so I get only one class name?

How can I extend a component returned by withStyles function as a higher order component?

Comment: Just to be clear, you're looking to add additional styles from within the component file? Something like how the demos show classes.root, classes.drawer, wtc?

Comment: Not exactly. I edited the question to provide a better example.

Comment: I don't see styled-components anywhere. You sure the library's components are styled by styled-components?

Comment: Yes. Sorry. Maybe I made a mistake at naming things. With styled components I didn't mean the styled-components library, but HoC components returned by withStyles material-ui function.

Comment: I have the same issue, same situation where i'm extending a custom component that is exported withStyles(s)(bla). I'm my mind, withStyles should only return the exact same component passed as parameter but with a new prop set (classes) and thats it. Don't know what its doing, but its not right